# Is there any third party which can support by both iOS4 and iOS5?

Tags: iphone, json, ios5, ios4, jsonserializer

Is there any way to develop web-service base application using third party json which can run on both iOS5 and iOS4? So, It can be run on both iOS4 And iOS5.We know that iOS5 is not supporting third party json library where iOS4 is not supporting NSJSONSerialization. Please help me, If anybody know any solution and way to do this.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What do you mean, iOS5 is not supporting third party json library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit). Everybody's using it, it's simply and very fast.

Comment: Thanks.I didn't know that json library is also available for iOS5.I am sure that It's also supported by iOS4.Am i right?